# Buildroot on Raspberry Pi With Lightning Bolt on Boot

Tags: boot-issues, pi-3b+, buildroot

I'm attempting to get a minimal buildroot system up and running on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ but after I've flashed the SD card, installed the card, powered up the pi, and connect an HDMI cable, I only ever get the multicolor screen with the lightning bolt.

From what I understand, I should be getting a getty prompt with the ability to login. I've followed the instructions on the buildroot GitHub page: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/master/board/raspberrypi but with no avail. I run the following commands to build the image:

`make raspberrypi3_64_defconfig`

`make`

The result of my build contains the following files/directories:

```
cm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb 
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
boot.vfat
rootfs.ext2  
rootfs.ext4
rpi-firmware 
sdcard.img 
zImage
```

I then flash the card with 
`sudo dd bs=4M status=progress if=sdcard.img of=/dev/sdb`

I don't see any options explicitly for the raspberry pi 3 b+, I just assumed the raspberrypi3_64_defconfig was the correct configuration.

Getting to a login screen will be a huge win for me! Thanks.

Comment: do you know what the "lightning bolt" means? usually means you don't have a good power supply

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I am aware. What's interesting is I have successfully booted several other OSs with the same exact hardware setup. This makes me believe that I have done something wrong with building the image. Maybe old firmware? Not sure.

Comment: oh ... that is interesting, not sure I can help then

Comment: Which model Rpi do you have? Your text says B+ and your tag says 3B+. And what exact command did you use? The readme lists specific commands for each board.

Comment: @T.M. Sorry, I left off the 3. I have the RPI 3 B+  with ARM v8 A53 arch.

Comment: Ok, but the other part of my question was equally important. Can you update your question with what commands you used? You're getting different file outputs than the readme describes for the 3b+. The readme implies you should get the directory bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb

Comment: @T.M. I updated my question with the make commands that I am running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was. For some reason, the version of build root I pulled down didn't contain the proper files for the Pi 3 B+. These are the steps that I followed:

1. `git clone https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot.git`
2. `cd buildroot`
3. `make raspberrypi3_defconfig`
4. `make`
5. `dd bs=4M status=progress if=./output/images/sdcard.img of=/dev/sdb`

I then put the card in and it booted like a champ. Now I can spend time configuring my OS with what I actually need! Yay!

To be clear, the file that I couldn't find when was this one: `bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb`. That was definitely the magic sauce that caused me to fail previously. Thanks @T.M. for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 2):

raspberrypi3_64_defconfig isn't even listed in the readme, I assume because it's experimental. Try

```
make raspberrypi3_defconfig
```

That's the one listed so it should be expected to work.

Comment: `raspberrypi3_64_defconfig` [is listed in the readme since May 20, 2021](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/eb3c965c8816519e3c07ad6f9fa6d17146b1cdab#diff-e97ddac59436f198e3bbac0b2308a7614cdde6c34f15d90ca4bfcc0b3b26332d).